# Room owners for The Garbage Collector: Nominations

Tags: discussion, chat, room-owners

[Community consensus](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/514/5) has decided that it's time to choose more official room owners (ROs) for our main chat room, [The Garbage Collector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146046/the-garbage-collector). ROs are responsible for some basic moderation tasks like pinning messages, clearing spam stars, and moving spam messages to trash rooms. This will be the first of two stages in an election, where we'll elect at least six ROs. **Current ROs will not maintain their positions; they must run in the election.**

The election will work as follows (some wording copied from [CGCC's RO nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11320/new-tnb-room-owners-nominations-phase)):

1. For one week (lasting until UTC midnight on July 27th), nominations will be accepted on this meta post. The votes on the nominations here will not matter. Self-nominations are allowed. If you are nominated by someone else, you must accept the nomination to be considered a candidate (we don't want to elect someone who doesn't actually want the position).
2. After the nomination period, the election will begin, lasting for one week (until UTC midnight on August 3rd). At the end of the election, winning candidates will be submitted to the moderators and current room owners for approval and instatement as new room owners.

The top six candidates with at least a 2:1 upvote:downvote ratio in the election phase will be chosen, with the exception that current mods (who may run) don't count toward this number (so that mods are able to run without taking up the spot of someone who doesn't already have the ability to use RO tools, as mods do).

Nominations don't need to be super long, but should provide some info on why the candidate would be a good fit for the position, and link to their PLDI **and** chat accounts.

Comment: To whoever's downvoting every single post, nomination, and discussion related to this RO election, could you please explain why? If you have any concerns with how it's being done there was plenty of time to discuss those, and still is to a degree.

Answer (score 8):

## Rydwolf Programs [[PLDI]](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/5/rydwolf-programs) [[chat]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/347075/rydwolf-programs)

[image: Active during daylight in North America (shockingly healthy sleep schedule for a programmer]

[image: Consistently active on all days of the week. A bit more on Monday. How else am I gonna cope with Mondays?]

Hi! I'm Rydwolf, a current RO of the GC. I've been an elected RO of CGCC's main room, The Nineteenth Byte, for a little over two years, so I've had some experience with the RO tools. I've also been a dedicated member of this site; I created the proposal for it, as well as its original chat room, and I've consistently worked to keep the site moderated (I'm currently the top reviewer in five of the seven review queues).

As a room owner, my primary goal is to ensure everyone feels comfortable participating, and that on-topic discussion is prioritized over off-topic (but I'm still a big fan of some off-topic discussion :p).

Comment: Sorry, what is "CGCC"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), another site on the network

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the subtitle. I understand a lot of the most active users here are also old-timers there.

Answer (score 5):

## Bbrk24, self-nomination

### [main](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/15/bbrk24) and [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/543214/bbrk24) profiles

Activity:

[image: active hours graph]

Similar hours to @Ginger, but unlike them, I'm more active during the week than on weekends.

Admittedly, I don't have any experience with RO'ing and I haven't had enough rep to handle chat flags. However, according to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146046/the-garbage-collector, I am the most active chat user!

[More info about me on CGCC meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25681/106545)

Answer (score 5):

#### Self-nomination for [Adám](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/7/ad%C3%A1m)

I'm not the most active chat user, but if you look carefully, you'll see that I'm actually around most of the time:
[image: Chat activity graphs]<sup>← except Saturdays</sup>

What I offer is a RO that can usually respond quickly if asked to step in to deal with conflicts, noise, spam, etc. This should enable broader community pariticipation in moderation, since it gives others indirect courses of action.

I'm currently RO in our chat room, and has been in the main Code Golf room for over two years, in addition to having moderated [a quite active programming-related chat room](https://apl.chat) since I started it, six-and-a-half years ago.

As one of the first users here, I'm quite familar with our site, having supported it from the early beginnings, and being continuously active in and monitoring our meta site. The health of the community is dear to me, as it is the perfect fit for [my job](https://www.dyalog.com/meet-team-dyalog.htm#Adam).

Answer (score 4):

## Self-nomination for Ginger

[Main Profile](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/9/ginger) [Chat Profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/533049/ginger)

Active hours:

[image: active hours]

Essentially, I'm active during daylight hours for eastern North America.

### About

- I've been active in CGCC/TNB for about a year and a half, but in that time I'd say I have matured quite a bit and learned much about its culture.
- I'm a member of the PLDI Mafia (along with Rydwolf, lyxal, mousetail and a few others), one of the earliest supporters of the proposal, and user #9 on the site.
- I'm an RO of [Vyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal), and lead developer (inasmuch as these projects have a lead) for Vyxal Bot and the Crosshatch REPL.
- I was an RO pro tempore for The Garbage Collector, added when the room was originally created, so I have experience moderating it already.
- For what it's worth, I'm in the [frequently in room list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146046/the-garbage-collector) for TGC.

If you want to ask me anything, you can easily do so [in TGC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146046/the-garbage-collector).

Answer (score 4):

### Redz, self-nomination

[Main](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/148/redz-supports-the-strike) and [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/565912/redz-supports-the-strike) profiles.

Activity (I follow AEDT time):

[image]

I've been around since site proposal and through the commitment stages, and was one of the earliest users to follow + commit. I've also visited the site every day, and the Garbage Collector nearly as frequently, and I'm an active user on Meta PLDI.

I haven't had experience as an RO, and I'm unable to handle chat flags. However, I believe I understand the general rules of what's on-and-off-topic in main chat rooms, and I'll be able to handle flags and discussions without bias.

Answer (score 3):

## Self-nomination for Seggan

Ayo, me name is [Seggan](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/45) ([chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/526756)). I am one of the current room owners. My main experience ROing is in the [Vyxal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal) room in Code Golf, as well as a few other language-specific rooms created over the years. Of course, I've RO'd the Area51 chatroom as well as The Garbage Collector for a few months now. As such, I have quite a bit of experience moderating conversations and such. I am user #45 on this site, and am one of the early committers/followers before beta. I am also apparently the 5th most active user in The Garbage Collector. Not much more to say. Hope you liked this nomination post, be sure to like and subscribe.

### Active hours

[image: Active hours]

Basically, I'm active during the day in the Eastern time zone.