# Conclusion of Room Owner nominations/election for The Garbage Collector

Tags: discussion, chat, room-owners

[Community consensus](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/514/5) has decided that it's time to choose more official room owners (ROs) for our main chat room, [The Garbage Collector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146046/the-garbage-collector). ROs are responsible for some basic moderation tasks like pinning messages, clearing spam stars, and moving spam messages to trash rooms. About a week ago, a [nominations post](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/room-owners-for-the-garbage-collector-nominations) was posted, with plans to hold an election for six non-mod ROs.

Six users were nominated. This means none of the six positions are contested. However, there was a second requirement set out based on the election votes: candidates needed an upvote:downvote ratio of 2:1 or higher. In chat, it was decided following some [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64074660#64074660) and 24 hours without objections that, in order to avoid a week long uncontested election, all of the nominees would be added as Room Owners, as they all had 2:1 vote ratios in the nomination phase, making it very unlikely any wouldn't meet the requirements in an election phase.

So, as of July 2023, four of The Garbage Collector's existing ROs have maintained their positions:

[image: Rydwolf Programs]

[image: Ginger]

[image: Seggan]

[image: Adám]

Two ROs are being added (congrats to both!):

[image: Bbrk24]

[image: Redz]

One RO is being removed, who was added early on but hasn't been active:

[image: emanresu A]

Comment: I totally missed this. It all happened so quickly.